# ImportError: No module named google.auth

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, firebase-admin

When I try to import `firebase_admin` in `python 2.7` I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named google.auth

This is the [DockerFile](https://github.com/ammaratef45/Attendance/blob/master/Dockerfile) I'm using.

I've installed Python from the source code using

```sh
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/Python-2.7.tgz
tar xvzf Python-2.7.tgz
cd Python-2.7
./configure
make
make install
```

Then I've installed pip and firebase admin by running:

```sh
apt-get install -y python-pip
pip install firebase-admin
```

Then I ran `import firebase_admin` inside the python shell.
I got the error:

> ImportError: No module named google.auth

I've run `pip show google.auth` and got the following output:

```
Name: google-auth
Version: 1.6.3
Summary: Google Authentication Library
Home-page: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth- 
library-python
Author: Google Cloud Platform
Author-email: jonwayne+google-auth@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: cachetools, six, pyasn1-modules, rsa
```

I've run `echo $PYTHONPATH` and got this:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

That means the `google.auth` is installed and its directory is in the `PYTHONPATH`, why python can't find it? and how to fix it?

Comment: So what is the problem in the end?

Comment: @CharlesXu I've edited the question, I found that I was forgetting something too

Comment: @CharlesXu I've edited the question again, please check the last sentence

Comment: Which python interpreter did you use that caused the error?

Comment: @Baily I use local built python 2.7, the whole docker image used it provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the image of `adamantium/flutter` and saw in the Dockerfile that it depends on `ubuntu:18.04` which is shipped with Python2 directly, as mentioned in PEP-394 (see the link below for more information on this).

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/

So, I don't understand why you want to re-install it again. What happened is that you have used a Dockerfile that installs another version of Python2 in `/usr/local/bin/` and overwrites the symbolic link that points to the original Python2 as you can see in `docker build` logs

```
if test -f /usr/local/bin/python -o -h /usr/local/bin/python; \
then rm -f /usr/local/bin/python; \
else true; \
fi
(cd /usr/local/bin; ln python2.7 python)
```

You can then verify the current Python interpreter within the container:

```
root@9b9176e6c26c:/# which python
/usr/local/bin/python

root@9b9176e6c26c:/# python --version
Python 2.7
```

Meanwhile, I have removed the part which installs Python2 from the Dockerfile and got this.

```
root@e6dd827dac1d:/# which python
/usr/bin/python

root@e6dd827dac1d:/# python --version
Python 2.7.15rc1
```

Then import what you want directly:

```
root@e6dd827dac1d:/# python -c "import firebase_admin"

root@e6dd827dac1d:/# echo $?
0
```

You can see that it succeeded by returning code 0.

Dockerfile after modification:

```
FROM adamantium/flutter

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential && \
    apt-get install -y zlib1g && \
    apt-get install zlib1g-dev && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/Python-3.6.7.tgz && \
    tar xvzf Python-3.6.7.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.6.7 && \
    ./configure && make && \
    make install

RUN apt-get install -y python-pip && \
    pip install firebase-admin
```

Comment: That explains it, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Upon building your docker image: `docker build -t test -f Dockerfile .` I had different results than what you described.

- The result of `echo $PYTHONPATH` returned nothing
- Running the python interpreter located at `/usr/local/bin/python` allowed me to import firebase_admin

For reference:

```
$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import firebase_admin
>>>
```

If you plan on running a script within the Dockerfile (i.e. CMD/ENTRYPOINT) I recommend passing in the full path of the working interpreter, which in this case is located at `/usr/local/bin/python`